# Search Facebook movies from iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook

Am I able to search Facebook movies images / title to show up in my iOS App? I want to make available for user to brows FB movie database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "FB Movie database". You could use the `/search` endpoint to search for movie pages, but there's no way to filter for "movies only":

```
GET /search?q=terminator%203&type=page
```

returns

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Movie", 
      "name": "Terminator 3: Rise of the Machines", 
      "id": "458993734171141"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Video game", 
      "name": "Terminator 3: The Redemption", 
      "id": "112560575422064"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Book", 
      "name": "Terminator 3 (novel)", 
      "id": "112353638775758"
    }, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

for example.